# How to know when commercial app will be published

Tags: software-center, application-development, development

Is there a way for me to know when my app will be published. I assume there is a list of apps which needs to be reviewed, so I would like to know on which place is my app, in that table. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have a queue listing and the time is based on a number of factors. If you've submitted as per the instructions (packaging source, installed in /opt or a tarball) then the packaging will move faster.

The US Holidays have created a fairly large backlog which we are working on as quickly as possible.

You can always use the feedback mechanism in MyApps to "prod" us a bit.